# Apply one argument to multiple functions

Tags: functional-programming, elm

Is there a way to apply one argument to multiple functions in elm?

in the example, `x` would be applied to each `isDiv` function

```
isDiv : Int -> Int -> Bool
isDiv x y =
    modBy x y == 0


isLeapYear : Int -> Bool
isLeapYear x =
    x (isDiv 4 && isDiv 100 || isDiv 400)
```

Ended up doing this

```
isLeapYear : Int -> Bool
isLeapYear x =
    let
        isDiv y =
            modBy y x == 0
    in
    isDiv 4 && not (isDiv 100) || isDiv 400
```

Comment: This doesn't directly relate to the question, but since it's clearly about leap years I think you meant to negate the `isDiv 100` part.

Comment: Clojure has a function called `juxt` https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt I'm not sure if Elm has something similar, but it might serve as inspiration.

Comment: I was playing around with the code and forgot to readd the not e.e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a helper function inside `isLeapYear` like this:

```
isLeapYear : Int -> Bool
isLeapYear x =
    let isDivX n = isDiv x n
    in isDivX 4 && isDivX 100 || isDivX 400
```